# Implementing copy-constructor using assignment operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling assignment operator in copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639017/calling-assignment-operator-in-copy-constructor)

I find that I am always implementing my copy-constructors as wrappers of my assignment operator, as follows:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& orig)
{
    *this = orig;
    //Sometimes I use the following - they are equivalent, right?
    //this->operator=(orig);
}
```

I am wondering if there is something wrong with this, or if there is ever a situation where the above would be wrong, or cause unwanted results.

Comment: If you *need* to implement a copy constructor in the first place, chances are that this just won't work. Assignment requires a fully constructed object on the left side, and if there is a need for this constructor, `*this` will likely not be a valid object.

Comment: @UncleBens By the time a constructor starts running, the object is fully constructed. Anything that needs to be done prior to full construction must be in the initialization list.