# How to use both default and custom copy constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have a long class with a lot of data members. I want to write a copy constructor for it. But, if I write my own copy constructor, I lose access to the default copy constructor.

I just want to repair a few pointers in my own copy constructor. So I want to have a shallow copy of the object which can be done by the default copy constructor.

Is there a possibility to access the default copy constructor when I have my own copy constructor?

Comment: How will other code know to call the default or your constructor?

Comment: @Mark As I understand OP wants to use default ctor **inside** own ctor only.

Comment: @Mark: Ofc my copy constructor. I just want a shallow copy of the object before invocation of my copy contructor. Later I can do my own coping/fixing actions.

Comment: Could you illustrate with some short sample code how you could benefit from a default constructor being called in the copy constructor?

Comment: @juanchopanza: The benefit is easy. I have shallow copy of an object and I don't have to do it by myself.

Comment: @pablo bot wouldn't you get the shallow copy anyway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap the things you don't want to change in a struct, and derive (privately) from it.  In your copy constructor, simply invoke the copy constructor of your base class.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about it is that it supports the questioner in what's probably folly: having "a few" pointers that need special treatment, in a single class. It does what was asked for, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop There are probably other criticisms one could make as well.  Having a class with enough members to make this an issue, for example.  As for the pointers... without knowing why they need special treatment, it's hard to be sure, but _if_ it's an issue of dynamically allocated objects and deep copy, then more than one pointer in any one class is a recipe for problems.

Answer (score 8):

No you cannot have both default and your own copy c-tor.

But there are two workarounds with this problem:

---

**1** Enclose your pointers in some class with defined copy semantics

Example:

```
class A {
public:
private:
   int trivial1;
   int trivial2;
   ...
   SomePointer  nontrivialMember;
};

class SomePointer {
public:
  SomePointer(const SomePointer&); // here the non trivial part of A copy semantics
  int* nonTrivialMember;
};
```

---

**2** Enclose the trivial parameters in some trivial structure

Example:

```
class A {
public:
   A(const A& o) : data(o.data) {
     // non trivial part
   }
private:
   struct Data {
     int trivial1;
     int trivial2;
     ...
   } data;
   int* nontrivialMember;
};
```

---

I would always select the first solution.

[UPDATE]

There is also 3rd solution, very similar to my second, enclose your trivial part in privately inherited base class. I'd still prefer the 1st solution.

Comment: So what is the motivation behind choosing the first solution

Comment: @user877329 The main reason for selecting first is to implement only necessary copy/move semantics. By necessary I mean such which cannot be defined by compiler itself. In first solution you deal with pointer only. In the other solutions you must also copy this trivial part of a class.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach to this would be to wrap up the pointers into classes that will perform the '*repair*' manually in their copy constructor, then you can happily use the default copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to call the default copy constructor from an user defined copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the default or your own, not both. If you want to choose different functionality for different objects you should just write a member function that handles that case.

```
void DeepCopy(MyClass* rhs);
```

For example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access default copy ctor if you created your own - compiler just doesn't generate it. But ther is workaround - split you class into data structure and logic.

See example:

```
struct Data
{
  int i;
  std::string s;

  Data(): i(), s() {}
};

class Code: private Data
{
public:

  Code() {}

  Code(const Code& rhs): Data(rhs) // Call default copy ctor
  {
     i = 42; // Your copy part
     return *this;
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a simple memcpy() instead of the impossible call to the implicit (compiler generated) copy constructor, as the example shown below:

```
Class Foo
{
public:
   ...
   Foo (Foo & other) {
      // copies trivial part (and non-trivial part with possible wrong values)
      memcpy(this, &other, sizeof(Foo));

      // your non-trivial part here, overwrites the wrong values (if any) above.
   }
}
```

Yet the side-effect is that the memcpy() will also copy those non-trivial part, which is a waste.  If the non-trivial part does not contain too much space, I will prefer my solution.

For example, a class like below wastes only 4 byte copy of the one pointer, assuming the size of a pointer is 4 bytes.

```
Class Bar
{
    int x, y, z;

    // memcpy() wastes these 4 bytes copy,
    // since actual copy constructor wants a new string
    string *s;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... (C++11, don't know if it works on older std)
Not sure why it doesn't end up in an endless loop.

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const Foo &orig) {
     *this = orig;
     ... exchange pointers, do own stuff
  }
```

Comment: it doesn't end in an endless loop because `*this = orig` calls copy assignment, not copy ctor.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639017/calling-assignment-operator-in-copy-constructor on thoughts about this method

Comment: makes sense, thanks for the link! despite the mentioned cons I am in favor of the pro, but that really depends on the class...