# Getting debug assertion errors in program

Tags: c++

I'm just trying to create a simple program to practice some C++, but I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this current error. The output provides my desired outcome, but after succesful output I keep getting debug assertion errors. Is it a memory leak or something? I have no idea what it could be.

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
class Record {
    char* rec;
public:
    Record();
    Record(const char*);
    Record(const Record&);
    ~Record();
    void display(std::ostream&);
    Record& operator=(const char*);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record& r);
```

cpp:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "Record.h"

Record::Record() {
    rec = nullptr;
}

Record::Record(const char* s) {
    if(s != nullptr) {
    rec = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
    strcpy(rec, s);
    } else {
    *this = Record();
    }
}

Record::Record(const Record& r) {
    *this = r;
}

Record::~Record() {
    delete [] rec;
}

void Record::display(std::ostream& os) {
    os << rec;
}

Record& Record::operator=(const char* s) {
    if (rec != s)
    delete [] rec;
    if(s != nullptr) {
    rec = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
    strcpy(rec, s);
    } 
    else {
    rec = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Record& r) {
    r.display(os);
    return os;
}
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Record.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Record rec1("inheritance"), rec2 = rec1;

    cout << rec1 << endl;
    cout << rec2 << endl;
    rec1 = "overloading";
    cout << rec1 << endl;
    rec2 = rec1;
    cout << rec2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, please use std::string and drop using the char*. Once you do that, then more than likely your errors will go away, and you don't need that assignment operator.

Comment: Did you actually step through your code with a debugger, to check where exactly the exception is thrown?

Comment: @onemic - where is your main() program that duplicates the error?

Comment: Where is the assignment operator that takes a Record&?  `Record& operator=(const Record&);`  Right now, you have no user defined assignment operators that takes a Record&.  Therefore your copy constructor is all messed up since it doesn't really do anything (except invoke the compiler-generated assignment operator).

Comment: @onemic - Your copy constructor is still incorrect.  It doesn't call the assignment operator you wrote.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie's analysis is right -- I missed that you were in fact invoking the default assignment operator from your constructors. I've updated my answer. In any case calling an assignment operator from the copy constructor isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call the assignment operator, `*this =`, from the `const char*` and copy constructors. This is generally bad practise. In your case, because you haven't defined an assignment operator that takes a `const Record&`, the default assignment operator is called, which simply copies *the pointer* and does a *shallow copy*, meaning that both `Record`s will have the same pointer in their `rec`s -- this was pointed out and described in detail in [PaulMcKenzie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22887287/834521). However even if you did define that assignment operator, if you did the same thing as your existing assignment operator, the member variable `rec` would be uninitialized and `delete`ing it causes undefined behaviour.

See [Calling assignment operator in copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639017/calling-assignment-operator-in-copy-constructor) for a discussion, and what you could do instead of calling the assignment operator from a constructor.

*Edit*

One way to make your program work would be for your constructors to look something like this.

```
void Record::InitFrom(const char* s)
{
    if(s != nullptr) {
        rec = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
        strcpy(rec, s);
    } else {
        rec = nullptr;
    }
}

Record::Record(const char* s) {
    InitFrom(s);
}

Record::Record(const Record& r) {
    InitFrom(r.s);
}
```

You could also incorporate the new `InitFrom` method into your assignment operator.

```
Record& Record::operator=(const char* s) {
    if (rec != s) { // this test only really necessary if assigning from Record
        delete [] rec;
        InitFrom(s);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

You also might have an assignment operator that takes a `const Record&`. You *do* need the destructor.

Comment: gotcha. I thought you always needed a copy constructor whenever you have an assignment operator, that's why I included it. Removing that and the deconstructor made it work without the debug assertion errors

Comment: @onemic - Your program does not work if the copy constructor is called.  Look closely at your copy constructor.  It is calling the assignment operator for Record&, but you didn't write one.  So no, your program is not working.  Try this `int main() {  Record rec1("inheritance");Record rec2 = rec1; }`  I immediately got an assertion error on exit of main().

Comment: @onemic In this case you _do_ need a destructor and a copy constructor, for the same reason you need an assignment operator, namely that you have a member variable `rec` whose memory you are managing manually (as comments under your question state, if you used a `string` instead, you would have no problem, but I'm assuming this is just an exercise to further your understanding of C++). The specific problem I spotted in your code was that by calling the assignment operator from the constructors the assignment operator was dealing with an uninitialized `rec`.

Comment: This would be so simple if I could change the assignment operator to take a Record&, but this is a practice question from one of my C++ courses, so I assume that they made the assignment operator take const char* for a reason. Currently I have it working with no errors, but that's only if the copy constructor and deconstructor are removed and based on what TooTone is saying, that's still a bad idea. How would I get it to work well with this current setup?

Comment: @onemic I've updated my answer, hopefully this makes things clearer (note I haven't compiled or tested it).

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this as an answer, since it is important in how your class behaves and concluding that "everything is working" is one of the reasons why C++ is not that easy of a language.

The main() program you wrote does not test something very simple.  Look here:

```
int main() {
   Record rec1("inheritance");
   Record rec2 = rec1;
}
```

If you debug this code, you will see that this function is called for the rec2 = rec1 line:

```
Record::Record(const Record& r) {
    *this = r;
}
```

Ok, so the copy constructor is called.  But what does this line of code do?:

```
*this = r;
```

It does *not* call the assignment operator that you wrote that takes a const char*.  Instead, it calls the default assignment operator that takes a Record&,  The problem is that -- you didn't write one.  So what winds up happening is that the compiler generated assignment operator is called, which does a shallow copy.

In the main() program, when main() returns, both rec2 and rec1 will have their respective destructors called.  The problem is that rec2 will delete the pointer value, ok, but then rec1 will delete the same pointer value (no good), causing a corruption of the heap.  I ran your code with Visual Studio 2013, and immediately an assertion dialog popped up when main() returned.

So you need to write a user defined assignment operator that takes this signature:

```
Record& Record::operator=(const Record&)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say for sure what's going one without seeing the value with which you have initialized the Record.  Based on your description of the program's behavior and the code, I can think of one possible explanation of what's happening, although there might be others.

My guess is the std::ostream is handing the char* like a c-string, which expects a sequence of charcters terminated by a \0.  If your Record has been initialized with a sequence of characters that doesn't terminate with a \0, it would keep doing pointer incrementation, streaming out a character at a time, until it reaches an invalid section of memory.  This will cause undefined behaviour, which might trigger a debug assertion in your implementation of the standard (i.e. the compiler you are using).

I provide you this guess as you say this is a learning exersize, so I don't question your class design but try to help you understand what's happening.  The comments elsewhere are quite relevant however.  If you have record store a std::string instead of a character array, this problem (and several other possible problems) will not occur.  That answer may not help you lean what you are trying to learn of course.

Comment: If the Record were initialized with a sequence of characters that wasn't null-terminated then it would surely fail on the `strcpy`? Notwithstanding, if you read mine and Paul's answers, you will see that there are far more serious problems than the unlikely event of initializing with a null-terminated string.